# How to add attributes to a core data class created with the data model?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm creating a todo app:

I created an entity in my projects .datamodel file, I added the entity an attribute of a string called "content" and created NSManagedObject subclass with the "editor" > "Create NSManagedObject subclass:

[image]

This class was created:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Targets : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * content;

@end
```

but now I want another "id" attribute to do I can give each todo an id...
How should I do this? is it ok to do it manually? since I generated it from the entity model it feels like I need to create a new entity to do that...?

If you can direct me, and maybe through an explanation how that works it would be awesome..maybe I dont understand something here and this is why I'm asking this question

Comment: You want to add attributes to this entity?

Comment: In light of the fact that there may be an Xcode bug with replacing the file, you can delete the file from your project and have Xcode generate a new one.

Comment: it is always wise to gerate two classes per entity: one for machine that you don't touch and can be re-created, one for humans, that will contain your changes and methods and wont be overwrite. http://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In light of the fact that Xcode appears to have a bug which prevents it from appropriately replacing your CoreData files, I've rewritten my answer with a workaround.

1. Delete the originally generated class file:

[image]

(Click move to trash.)

2. Add the attribute:

[image]

3. Generate the class in the exact manner you generated the original we deleted in step 1:
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

So, the solution to your problem is actually quite simple:

To add another attribute to your *entity*, you can just approach it exactly in the same way as you did with the `content` attribute. Just add the attribute within the graphical editor, just like you did before with `content`, and then again, use Xcode's built-in functionality to generate the classes, in the same way as you did before.

What will happen is that Xcode overrides the formerly generated files, and replaces them with a new version that now has the attributes. There is no harm in doing that process as often as you like. :)

**EDIT:**
Short side note, you need to remember to *delete* the app from your device (or the simulator) after you changed the data model, because otherwise the app will crash because your new Core Data model is not consistent with the one you used before.
Second, if you want to add functionality to your data model classes (which you should do with much care anyway, but maybe some utility Core Data functions or so...), you should make use of *iOS categories*, so that the code which you wrote for that doesn't get deleted when you regenerate your model classes. The Stanford Lecture on iOS development has a [great introduction session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2sZ9IjDBzs) on Core Data where this approach is explained in detail!

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, and even had posted an answer of my own, outlining these steps... however when I actually do this, the file I'm supposedly overwriting doesn't seem to change.

Comment: I join the comment :) , it looks like something happened in the background but my new attribute was not added to the "Targets" class.. @nburk

Comment: hmmm... that's really strange, I used Core Data in several project and usually approached it exactly like I described, and it was always working without a problem... however, I just tried it myself and indeed, Xcode doesn't seem to override the files properly any more (I hadn't tried it on Xcode 6 before actually...). is this a bug in Xcode?

Comment: Must be.  Even Xcode says it's going to replace the file, but doesn't actually do it.

Comment: anyway, a simple workaround for the issue of the files not being properly overridden could be to delete the files before regenerating a new one, that should work, right?

Comment: It does work, yes.  I just added that as a comment to the question.